# In what frame the three Kepler's laws are valid?

Tags: reference-frames, orbital-motion, inertial-frames, celestial-mechanics

Three Kepler's laws of planetary motion were formulated by Kepler by analysing obervations of Tycho Brahe. I am wondering **in what frame Tycho Brahe made his measurements and in what frame the Kepler’s laws are formulated.**

Kepler's law, in particular, modify Copernicus' laws that all planet revolve around the Sun in circular orbits. I have found in literature that Copernicus constructed a particular frame to get this description: the origin is the Sun, and the axis are almost orthogonal rays from the Sun to certain specific stars. What frame was used by Tycho Brahe and Kepler?

Comment: Note that you are asking two different things in the title and in the body of the question: Kepler's laws are not tied to any particular frame of reference and are valid in any one, but indeed an observer is in a specific frame of reference. I suggest you to modify the title to reflect the question in the body.

Comment: Actually Kepler's laws *deviate* from Copernicus' law, by stating that the planets
revolve in *elliptical* orbits, not in *circular* orbits.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: Kepler's laws DO depend on a frame. For example if one choses the first axis to be a ray from Sun to Earth (rather than to an appropriate star) then the orbit of Earth will not be elliptic. Indeed Earth will stay always on the first axis, and the orbit will be a segment.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch: That is correct.

Comment: The [Tychonic system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonic_system) was *geocentric*.

Comment: @Pm: This is something different. Tychonic system is an incorrect model of the solar system which Brahe suggested as a summary of his observations. Based on the same observations, Kepler suggested a different model which is correct. My question is what coordinate system was used by Brahe to make his measurements. At the moment I do not discuss conclusions and models which followed from these measurements.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano : You are right that the frames in which Tycho and Kepler worked may not be the same.  I have edited the question.

Comment: The ovservations themselves can only be done in a ground-based coodinate system in earth, right?  You pick a point, and you have a spherical coordinate system centered on that point?  

When translating the observations into theoretical conclusions like keplers laws, one would do some sort of coordinate transformation first, right?  Which of these two coordinate systems are you asking about?

Comment: @JerrySchirmer : I do not know how Tycho and Kepler worked.  This is exactly my question.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uraniborg), Tycho used the [equatorial coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equatorial_coordinate_system) for extra precision.

> To increase the accuracy of his readings further, he utilized the equatorial coordinate system instead of the zodiacal coordinate system with his specially designed instruments. [25]

> [25] [Tycho Brahe's Observations and Instruments | High Altitude Observatory](https://www2.hao.ucar.edu/Education/FamousSolarPhysicists/tycho-brahes-observations-instruments)

I *assume* Tycho mainly used the traditional [ecliptic latitude & longitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic_coordinate_system), which have been used since Babylonian times, and which were the standard for all astronomical tables. FWIW, data from the [Babylonian Astronomical Diaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_astronomical_diaries), which spanned seven centuries of astronomical and meteorological observations, formed the basis of the tables prepared by astronomers like Ptolemy and Hipparchus.

Answer (score 0):

All I know about Kepler laws is that they are derived from the principle of central forces such that M = dL / dt = 0. He didn't consider any reference system particularly. He supposed that the full transit is contained in a plane ( which can be derived from the previous statement ), and he also used polar coordinates that fit perfectly with this problem

Comment: The reference system IS important. See my answer to  Massimo Ortolano's comment above.